# Switch statement : if input not a digit (1 to 9) or a letter (a to z) output << "error" ? C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

How can I output an "error" message if the input is not a letter from a to z or a digit from 1 to 9.
For exemple, if the user inputs '%', how can I output "error" ?

I tried this :

```
if ((name.letter <= a) && (name.letter >= z)) {
   cout << "error";
}
```

but I guess it's just not C++ code...

Comment: It _could_ be C++ code if we knew the type of `name`.

Comment: @Hugo Do you mean `std::string`?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/ZpaaibDkqadc4mbq2Xifg7

Comment: The code won't compile because `stirng` is not defined. Please answer my question.

Comment: ^^here is my code, I'm not sur what 'std::string' means, I'm just starting coding in general...

Comment: I also imported those libraries : #include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Comment: Then you are using [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) because you use `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: This might be a bit off topic, but if you learn to code because you have programming lessons in school or something, you should probably ask your teacher or friends who are good at it for explanations. But if you do this all by yourself, I'd suggest to find a good book or online guide and stick to it. This way you will be able to avoid problems that are too hard for you, at least before you familiarize yourself enough with C++.

Answer (score 2):

There are useful functions in standard library [`cctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype).

example:

```
#include <cctype>

if (!islower((unsigned char)name.letter) && (!isdigit((unsigned char)name.letter) || name.letter == '0')) {
    cout << "error";
}
```

If the type of `name` is `std::string`, it may be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::cout;

int main(void) {
    std::string name = "1%";

    // use loop to check every characters
    bool valid = true;
    for (size_t i = 0, len = name.length(); i < len; i++) {
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char)name[i];
        if (!islower(c) && (!isdigit(c) || name[i] == '0')) {
            // illegal character is found
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
        cout << "error";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thing is I'm a noob and this is like chinese to me

Comment: it says : no member called 'letter'. and int main (void) : function definition not allowed here

Comment: The first code is a snipped which cannot be ran by itself, but the second code  [does work](https://ideone.com/gv8LoO). What do you have?

Comment: "function definition is not allowed here"

Comment: I have already seen the message in your comment and you did not provide any new information. It is not helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: are there no other ways to that that then, using a while statement maybe ?

Comment: Of course you can use while statement: `for(statement1; statement2; statement3) { statements; }` -> `{ statement1; while(statement2) { statements; statement3; } }`

Answer (score 1):

You could easily check your conditions with a few things that already exist in the standard library (`<cctype>`). Namely:

`isdigit` - Checks whether a character is a decimal digit character.

`isalpha` - Checks whether a character is an alphabetic letter.

These both take `int` arguments, but you could do something like the following:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
if(!(isdigit(c) && c != '0') && !isalpha(c)) {
  std::cerr << "Error!\n";
}
```

Note that `isalpha` will return `true` if `c` is a letter - this means uppercase or lowercase. If you really need one or the other, you could use `islower` or `isupper`.

Since `name` is a `std::string`, you could do the following:

```
for(auto c: name) {
  if(!(isdigit(c) && c != '0') && !isalpha(c)) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << c << " is not a valid character\n";
    break; // or return or exit
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I output an "error" message

You have marked this post as C++.

One C++ way to handle this is:

```
void checkName(std::string name)
{
   const std::string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   const std::string digits  = "123456789";
   const std::string letterDigits (letters + digits);

   std::cout << "\nname '" << name << "'" << std::endl;

   size_t indx = name.find_first_not_of(letterDigits);

   if(indx != std::string::npos)
   {
      std::cerr << "error at indx " << indx << " == '" << name[indx] << "'\n" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "all chars of name '" << name << "' are letters or digits\n" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/ )   
{
   {
      std::string name = "dan%iel";
      checkName(name);
   }
   {
      std::string name = "daniel";
      checkName(name);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think 0 is included in "a digit from 1 to 9".

Answer (score -2):

Not with a switch statement! Just enclose the letters in single quotation marks, so they are treated as their ASCII values:

```
if ((name.letter <= 'a') && (name.letter >= 'z')) {
 cout << "error";
}
```

Switch statements can only be used to match specific cases you specify, not ranges of cases as in some other languages.

Comment: Assuming `name` is indeed a `std::string`, `letter` is not a member so this still won't compile.

Comment: So after trying @erip method with the following code :  
    http://paste.ofcode.org/34GAQFYQKJtmumFA8scJHU3      it gives me an error message as follow : no matching function isdigit and isalpha

Comment: @Hugo Do pose [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without omitting the headers you include.

Comment: @Hugo it's int isdigit ( int c );, so you can only pass in one character at a time, not a whole string. e.g.  `if (isdigit(name[0])) {etc}` to only pass the first character of the string to the isdigit() function